# Local Parse Database gives error in SwiftUI

Tags: parse-platform, swiftui, parse-ios-sdk

I'm trying to store objects in a local Parse datastore on the device itself. I get an error when retrieving the stored object: 'Method requires Pinning enabled.'

I've implemented 'Parse.enalbelLocalDatastore() in AppDelegate.swift. I tried to hard-code the object to be sure there was an object to retrieve.

```
let configuration = ParseClientConfiguration
        {
            $0.applicationId = "..."
            $0.clientKey = "..."
            $0.server = "..."

        }
        Parse.enableLocalDatastore()
        Parse.initialize(with: configuration)
...
func blancoUser() {
        let object = PFObject(className: "UserData")
        object["id"] = (UUID().uuidString)
        object["LoginName"] = "userName"
        object["PinCode"] = "00000"
        object["ScreenName"] = "test"
        object["YearOfBirth"] = 0

        object.pinInBackground()
    }
...

let query = PFQuery(className: "UserData")
        var users:[UserData] = [UserData]()

        query.fromLocalDatastore()
        query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: Error?) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            } else if let objects = objects
```

I want to get the variable 'users' with the locally stored user objects. What am I missing? Or does the ParseLocalDatastore work differently in SwiftUI.

Comment: Your blancoUser() method does not persist the record.  Calling pinInBackground() does not persist the record.  You should call the saveInBackground() on the new object.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to initialize the SDK like this?

```swift
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

  func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        let parseConfig = ParseClientConfiguration {
            $0.isLocalDatastoreEnabled = true
            $0.applicationId = parseApplicationId
            $0.clientKey = parseClientKey
            $0.server = parseServerUrlString
        }
        Parse.initialize(with: parseConfig)
  }
}
```

Reference: https://docs.parseplatform.org/ios/guide/#local-datastore

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion: this extra line made the error 'Method requires Pinning enabled.' disappear. However, there are no objects stored in the local database with the command 'object.pinInBackground()'

Comment: remove this line `object["id"] = (UUID().uuidString)` The ids are set in server side. You can't set your own ids.

Comment: Unfortunately, this makes no difference. Print of the object after removing the id:
object: <UserData: 0x6000024bd5c0, objectId: new, localId: (null)> {
    LoginName = userName;
    PinCode = 00000;
    ScreenName = test;
    YearOfBirth = 0;
}
It doesn't show up I the query:
users: []

Comment: In the code you send you are never setting the users var. Check the objects var inside the callback function.